# Struts 1.5 : how to display a value in textField

Tags: java, javascript, struts, struts-1

I want to display a value in a text box and i want to do it using javascript only.

here is the situation :

- when i click on calender image, it opens a window where month & year only displayed.
- the selected month & year are displayed in the label.

Now my requirement is to display the same in textbox, because i want to assign the same to bean property.

Code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
    <meta name="description" content="Javascript popup date and time picker control (javascript calendar)">
    <meta name="keywords" content="free JavaScript Calendar, javascript, client side, pop, popup, timestamp, date, picker, database, control">
    <noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1;  url=JavaScriptCheck.do">
    </noscript>
    <title><fmt:message key="sms.banking.title"/></title>
    <link href="css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="css/monthYearCalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <script src="js/common.js"> </script>

    <script language="javascript" src="js/PopupWindow.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" src="js/AnchorPosition.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/monthYearCalendar.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    monthYearCalendar.init("boxMonthYear",show);
     monthYearCalendar.init(
    $("#year").html("Year :"+monthYearCalendar.selectedYear),
    $("#month").html("Month :"+monthYearCalendar.monthNames[monthYearCalendar.selectedMonth - 1])

);


});
function show() {
    $("#month").html("Month :"+monthYearCalendar.monthNames[monthYearCalendar.selectedMonth - 1]);
     $("#year").html("Year :"+monthYearCalendar.selectedYear );


}
```

```
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0">
    <html:form action="monthlyChargeReport" method="POST">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="text" width="400">

    <tr>
    <td height="24"  colspan="3" class="formlabelcolheadselect">&nbsp;<fmt:message key="reports.sms"/> -<fmt:message key="report.monthlycharge"/></td>
       <tr>
            <td height="5" colspan="3" class="errormsg">&nbsp;<html:errors/></td>
        </tr>
         <tr  >
            <td class="msgtext">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="msgtext" id="month">Month :

            </td>
            <td>
               <html:text property="month" value="${monthYearCalendar.selectedMonth}"/>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
         <tr  >
            <td class="msgtext">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="msgtext" id="year">Year :
                <html:text property="year" value="${monthYearCalendar.selectedYear}"/>
            </td>
             <td  id="boxMonthYear"></td>
          </tr>

           <tr>
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr class="textsml" id=TDSHADE2 >
            <td align=left>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align=left>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align=left>


            <html:button property="button" value="Submit" styleClass="buttons" title="Submit" onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].action='monthlyChargeReport.do';document.forms[0].submit();" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<html:button property="button" value="Back" styleClass="buttons" title="Back"  onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].action='reportStats.do';document.forms[0].submit();" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="simpletext" id=TDSHADE2>
            <td colspan="4"class="simpletext"><div align="left"><fmt:message key="fields.mark"/></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><%@ include file="copyRight.htm"%></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
    <html:javascript formName="monthlyChargeForm"/>
</html:form>
```

- there are two text fields with property names month & year.
- i want to display the values in them

Answer (score 0):

text tag in struts does not support property attribute...so it will not show the values for that u can use s:property also if ur values are binded in action then you can use %{varible name } to get values http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/text.html